# videos showing vi or emacs productivity

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, vi

I use text editors like eclipse, xcode and netbeans and I am intrigued to see how much  productive are the developers using emacs or vi.

So I'd like to know if you know of any videos that show experimented vi or emacs developers at their highest productivity rates.

Note: I am not looking to start an editor war, I just want to see how uber-programmers work, what ever editor they use.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite Vim screencasts are by Derek Wyatt.  They're really well done, great job of explaining wide variety of features and his humor will bring a smile to your face.  Several of them include moves where he does something big very efficiently, but even the most basic ones should impress you with the efficiency of Vim:

http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/

Answer (score 6):

Check out http://emacsrocks.com for some nice and short emacs screencasts.

Answer (score 3):

For Vim, it's easy.

Try: http://vimcasts.org/

Vimcasts is great.

Comment: Thx. These tutorials are very helpful. But I am looking for a video showing vi or emacs productivity to impress others and myself.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for org-mode in emacs.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlTDSX0vRiA or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQAd41VAXWo&feature=related

Comment: Something that would actually be useful in development?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of Emacs screencasts available at the following URL:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsScreencasts